# Syntax issue on ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The error says syntax if not closed. I am unable to use this ampscript for my triggered email:

```
Set @Lead = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead","Name,Llave_Prospecto_SGC__c","Id", "=", _subscriberkey)

if RowCount(@Lead)> 0 then

Set @LeadRow = Row(@Lead, 1) Set @Name = FIELD(@LeadRow, "Name") 
Set @CustomId = FIELD(@LeadRow, "Llave_Prospecto_SGC__c")
SET @URL = CONCAT('http://google.com/', @CustomId)

else then

RaiseError('Unable to find Lead. Can't Send Email', true)

endif
]%%
```

update:
Error log when validating journey:

```
Error 1: Script IF Not Closed An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement. 
Invalid Content: 
if RowCount(@Lead)> 0 then 
Set @LeadRow = Row(@Lead, 1) 
Set @Name = FIELD(@LeadRow, 'Name') 
Set @CustomId = FIELD(@LeadRow, 'Llave_Prospecto_SGC__c') 
SET @URL = CONCAT('http://google.com/', @CustomId) 
else 
RaiseError('Unable to find Lead. There is an error in your email
```

Comment: Please remove `then` after `else` in last 4th line. And let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still getting the same error. I have added some updates. I am not able figure out the syntax issue

Comment: Typically I see this is you have some incorrect " or ' , this could happen if you copied/paste the code from word or something similar. Trying delete these and retypign them, or paste it in notepad to ensure you are using " ' and not a different character

Comment: thanks @EazyE I did take help of the documentation and copy pasted the code. I fixed it with your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, your error message was closing the quotes previously.
Also added a space after "Then"

```
    %%[
Set @Lead = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead","Name,Llave_Prospecto_SGC__c","Id", "=", _subscriberkey)

if RowCount(@Lead)> 0 then 

Set @LeadRow = Row(@Lead, 1) 
Set @Name = FIELD(@LeadRow, "Name") 
Set @CustomId = FIELD(@LeadRow, "Llave_Prospecto_SGC__c")
SET @URL = CONCAT("http://google.com/", @CustomId)

else
RaiseError("Unable to find Lead. Cant Send Email", true)

endif
]%%
```